# Partial page curl animation

Tags: iphone, curl, transition

I have a working transition using `UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp` however, I would like the animation to stop halfway through, much like the Maps application...Any thoughts on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Maps partial curl is a private API. You can find details of how to use it in Erica Sadun's book [*The iPhone Developer's Cookbook*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321555457), but you will get rejected from the App Store for using it.

Comment: Good to know...Guess I'll just do a page flip transition then.

Comment: As of iOS 3.2, this is no longer true.

Answer (score 11):

In iOS 3.2 and later, you can give your `UIViewController` a `UIModalTransitionStyle` of `UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl`. From the `UIViewController` [reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html), we see

```
typedef enum {
  UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical = 0,
  UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal,
  UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve,
  UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl,
} UIModalTransitionStyle;
```

So an example use case would be:

```
UIViewController *viewController;
// …create or retrieve your view controller…

// Note: The modalPresentationStyle must be UIModalPresentationFullScreen,
//       and the presenter must also be a full-screen view
viewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFullScreen;
viewController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl;
```

Comment: If you'd like to do this, but preserve a bottom toolbar (e.g., not a full-screen curl), see my solution [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11406056/1148702)

Answer (score 7):

I found a solution to add an UIView to UIViewController using Animation block.

m_Container is an UIView who contain my view animation (self).
self is an UIView.

CAUTION : You need to have import QuartzCore

To present view with page curl animation you can use :

```
-(void)PresentView
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 
                     animations:^{
                         CATransition *animation = [CATransition animation];
                         [animation setDelegate:self];
                         [animation setDuration:0.7];
                         [animation setTimingFunction:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
                         animation.type = @"pageCurl";
                         animation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
                         animation.endProgress = 0.65;
                         [animation setRemovedOnCompletion:NO];
                         [m_container.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"pageCurlAnimation"];  
                         [m_container addSubview:self];
                         ;}  
     ];    
}
```

And when you want hide this view you can use :

```
-(void)HideHelpView
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 
                     animations:^{
                         CATransition *animation = [CATransition animation];
                         [animation setDelegate:self];
                         [animation setDuration:0.7];
                         [animation setTimingFunction:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
                         animation.type = @"pageUnCurl";
                         animation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
                         animation.startProgress = 0.35;
                         [animation setRemovedOnCompletion:NO];
                         [m_container.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"pageUnCurlAnimation"];  
                         [self removeFromSuperview];

                         ;}  
     ];

}
```

Comment: Is this private API?  It seems to work perfectly but I don't see it in the docs.

Comment: This is not a private API, I just use UIView methods to animate a view (m_container for me). You just need to copy methods content in your own methods and change m_container by your view…

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will work, but the parameter to `+setAnimationRepeatCount:` can be a fraction.