# Rolling an image partially like in google maps

Tags: iphone, objective-c, google-maps, animation

Can someone tell me how I can realize the rolling / unrolling animation as in google maps for iPhone? Thanks.

Comment: It would nice if someone could provide me some pointers. I have an image, which I would like to roll partially and display it. And when the user wants, he / she can unroll the image and see it completely.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a public API on iPhone currently.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is the `PartialCurl` transition. Not sure if it is available on the iPhone. Might be an iPad (3.2) thing only.

Also see [Partial page curl animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1681315/partial-page-curl-animation)

Comment: Thanks, but I need a PartialCurl from left to right and backwards. So, its not a public API yet?